# How to redirect my own browser when typing url

Tags: redirect, browser-automation

So I type in facebook.com as a habit when I want to go Facebook. But I really dislike the wall thing (it makes me procrastinate a lot more). So I wondered if it is possible to let your browser learn when you type in "facebook.com" that it will replace it with another url with for example "facebook.com/subdomain".

My initial thought is that it might be possible to have a bash script running in the background, but I wouldn't know if this is possible with bash. Or maybe I should install a keylogger on my computer and then connect it to a bash script and whenever I type facebook.com it just automatically replaces it with facebook.com/subdomain ?

It's hard for me to unlearn habits, so that's why I want to investigate in this solution. I also think it's an interesting technical question in itself :)

Comment: You could most likely use a HTTP proxy, most are configurable that if you try to visit a URL it can redirect you somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-alias-8703/) Add-On for firefox. I am sure there should be a similar one for chrome if you are a chrome user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vimsha, thanks to your answer I was able to formulate way more specific search queries and I found the following link to be a really good answer for Chrome. You just have to change your settings.

http://www.imkazu.com/create-an-alias-in-google-chrome-type-faster/

If someone knows how to script this: I'm still curious on how to go about it. It would be fun to somewhere type the emoticon ^^ for instance (in any program) and that it would be replaced with d(^_^)b

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a built-in way to do this using "[*keywords*](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html)". You just create a regular bookmark, then add a keyword to it, whenever you type that keyword in the browser it'll take you to the URL in the bookmark.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

In the above example, just typing "amazon" into the location bar will take you to the smile.amazon.com site.